# Mongify, database configuration file

Tags: mongodb, rubygems

I'm new at **mongodb** and **mongify**, I need to know where to find **database configuration file**, where is it? or how I create it?

Comment: Share what you have tried yet, So we can help based on it. Else go through MongoDB documentation.

Comment: I made the tutorial

Comment: http://linuxpitstop.com/migrate-mysql-to-mongodb-using-mongify-utility-linux/

Comment: install ruby gem, install devkit, config devkit, install mongify

Comment: But I cant create database.config file

Comment: can you share your database.config file